# Remove special/unprintable char from data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, special-characters

I have special chars in my sql tables and want to remove the special chars.

I have a function that strips out all chars that breaks XML.

```
fn_RemoveBadXMLChars(data)
```

which does something like this:

```
REPLACE(@ResultVar,'ÿ','')
```

Is there any easier way to remove every special chars instead of have 100 replace statments?

Comment: Any specific DBMS (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server...)?

Comment: @magic-c0d3r - did you ever get this solved?

Comment: Yes. I ended up using regex in my c# code to escape the char for XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a filter table that contains a record for each of the values you want to replace, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE FilterTable (
    FilterCharacter nchar(1) primary key
)

INSERT INTO FilterTable SELECT 'ÿ'
INSERT INTO FilterTable SELECT 'o'
```

And then use a variable to replace against your filter table like this:

```
DECLARE @ResultVar nvarchar(50)
SET @ResultVar = 'Bobbÿ'

SELECT @ResultVar = REPLACE(@ResultVar, FilterCharacter, '')
FROM FilterTable   

SELECT @ResultVar
```

Answer (score 1):

I like LittleBobbyTables answer, but another way would be to change your function code to something like this

```
   declare @value as varchar(100) = ' 98;;445498ÿThis is test     ';
   declare @len as int = LEN(@value);
   declare @i as int = 1;
   declare @work as varchar(1);
   declare @retValue as varchar(max) = '';
   declare @asciiValue as int

   while @i <= @len begin
     set @i = @i + 1;
     set @work = SUBSTRING(@value,@i,1);
     set @asciiValue = ASCII(@work);    
     -- Allow space(32) though } (125)
     if (@asciiValue between 32 and 125) and @asciiValue not in (38) -- Exclude
       set @retValue = @retValue + @work;
  end
  print @retValue
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined some solutions I found and in the end I had this as a result:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveSpecialChars] (@Input VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
DECLARE @Expression NVARCHAR(50) = '[^A-Za-z0-9]'
DECLARE @pos INT = PATINDEX('%' + @Expression + '%', @Input)

WHILE @Pos > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Input = STUFF(@Input, @pos, 1, '')
    SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%' + @Expression + '%', @Input)
END
RETURN @Input
END
```

You can define which characters to keep by modifying @Expression.
If you want to keep all characters and digits plus '@' you would change

```
DECLARE @Expression NVARCHAR(50) = '[^A-Za-z0-9]'
```

to

```
DECLARE @Expression NVARCHAR(50) = '[^@A-Za-z0-9]'
```

This removes everything but characters, digits and '@'.